# Pass additional statement to Django model query

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I have next Django statement

```
def get_companies_with_average_ratings_data(self, city=None, faculty=None):
    companies = Company.objects.values('name', 'id', 'logo_image').annotate(
        recommendations_score=Avg('companyinternshipreview__recommendation')
    ).annotate(
        apply_skills_score=Avg('companyinternshipreview__apply_skills')
    ).annotate(
        learn_new_score=Avg('companyinternshipreview__learn_new')
    ).order_by('-recommendations_score', '-apply_skills_score', '-learn_new_score')

    if city:
        companies = companies.filter(cities__name=city)

    if faculty:
        companies = companies.filter(companyinternshipreview__user__student__faculty__name=faculty)

    return companies
```

Not all companies have any added reviews with ratings, so for some of results, aggregate fields will contain NULL which makes sorting broken. I'm see companies without ratings first and only after that companies sorted by ratings.

I'm using PostgreSQL and I want to use 'COALESCE' to return average or 0 if no reviews exist. How can I pass this 'COALESCE' to Django model query in Django ORM way? I don't want to use raw SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [Coalesce](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce).

```
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

companies = Company.objects.values('name', 'id', 'logo_image').annotate(
    recommendations_score=Coalesce(Avg('companyinternshipreview__recommendation'), Value(0.0))
).annotate(
    apply_skills_score=Coalesce(Avg('companyinternshipreview__apply_skills'), Value(0.0))
).annotate(
    learn_new_score=Coalesce(Avg('companyinternshipreview__learn_new'), Value(0.0))
).order_by('-recommendations_score', '-apply_skills_score', '-learn_new_score')
```

Comment: Cool functionality, but might only be available in Django 1.8.

Comment: You can probably also manage it with ```extra```, but that's a bit more complicated and is deprecated as of 1.8.